# Get len of floats in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the len of the floats in a pandas df however I'm having some difficulty. I've tried converting the values to strings, so I can use len(str), however when I do so, i.e:

```
    df['col'].astype(str) or df['col'].values.astype(str)
```

the length of the floats change (because of the precision I guess). For example the value -0.225905 becomes -0.22590500000000002.

Is there a way to prevent this when converting to a str? I'd be equally grateful for a different method, so long as I can get the length of the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to round your column first to a specific range, and then later you can convert it to String, so in your cases:

```
df['col'] = round(df['col'], 6)
df['col'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can also return the pre_comma_digits len(number_whole) or only the post_comma_digits len(number_remainder).

```
def get_digits(decimal_number):
    ''' 
    This function returns the number of digits of a decimal_number.
    '''
    # remove sign from number
    # if you want to add the sign to the length you could add an if elif
    # statement here
    decimal_number_absolute = abs(decimal_number)
    # turn number to string
    decimal_number_string = str(decimal_number_absolute)
    number_whole = decimal_number_string.split('.')[0]
    number_remainder = decimal_number_string.split('.')[1]
    return len(number_whole) + len(number_remainder)

# test
number = -0.2341
print(get_digits(number))

# output
# 5

# apply to column of dataframe
df['my_column_length'] = df['my_column'].apply(get_digits)
```